# Pair of consecutive squarefree numbers with $n$ distinct prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $(a,a+1)$ be the smallest pair of squarefree numbers with $n$ distinct prime-factors,
if such a pair exists.

The solutions for small $n$ are:

\begin{array}
nn & (a&a+1) &  \text{Factorisation}\\ \hline
2 & 14 & 15  & [2, 1; 7, 1] & [3, 1; 5, 1]\\
3 & 230 & 231  & [2, 1; 5, 1; 23, 1] & [3, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1]\\
4 & 7314 & 7315 &  [2, 1; 3, 1; 23, 1; 53, 1] & [5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 19, 1]\\
5 & 378014 & 378015 & [2, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1; 67, 1]&  [3, 1; 5, 1; 11, 1; 29, 1; 79, 1]\\
6 & 11243154 & 11243155 & etc.
\end{array}

Does a pair exist for any natural number $n$?

Comment: Just checking: you mean *consecutive* squarefree numbers with *exactly* $n$ distinct prime factors *each*, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly n distinct prime factors.

Comment: This is related to https://oeis.org/A052215 (which unfortunately doesn't give any results beyond what's figured out in the answers to this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that it is possible for two consecutive numbers to have $n$ **or more** prime factors each (revised problem as mentioned in comments) is fairly easy: choose any $n$ different primes you like and let $m_1$ be their product; choose any other $n$ primes you like and let $m_2$ be their product.  Then you want to find $a$ satisfying
$$a\equiv0\pmod{m_1}\quad\hbox{and}\quad a\equiv-1\pmod{m_2}\ ;$$
but $m_1$ and $m_2$ have no common factor, so the Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees that this system of congruence equations has a solution.

However $a$ and $a+1$ will very likely have prime factors other than those we have "planted", so this does not ensure that $a$ and $a+1$ are squarefree.

Comment: The least solution for n = 7 is : 965009045  965009046

Comment: A solution for n = 8 (not necessarily the least) is : 87375685110 87375685111

Comment: A solution for n = 9 (not necessarily the least) is : 66851205793229 66851205793230

Comment: A solution for n = 10 (not necessarily the least) is : 1606135406268470 1606135406268471

Comment: A solution for n = 11 (not necessatily the least) is : 18526781664460440293  18526781664460440294

Comment: Least solution for n = 8 is (65,893,166,030 65,893,166,031)

Comment: Least solution for n = 9 is (5,702,759,516,090 5,702,759,516,091)

Comment: Least solution for n = 10 is (605,247,139,068,494 605,247,139,068,495)

Comment: Least solution for n = 11 is (78,971,815,814,237,709 78,971,815,814,237,710). Solution for n = 12 will probably take a while to find.

Comment: No solution for n = 12 with values < $1.8 * 10^{19}$.